# When is a summons considered served in England if it was sent by second class post?

Tags: england-and-wales, rules-of-court

If sent a court summons by one's local council, when is the summons considered served if it was sent by second class post?

**Background**

I queried a council tax bill as directed to by the council, but got a (non-favourable) decision. On the same day I received the decision I also received a court summons, which I am able to avoid if I pay the 'outstanding' council tax **plus** the court costs. The summons was sent by second class post and is dated 26th April, today being the 28th. I thought summons had to be sent first class post, and I can't find any information on when a summons sent by second class post would be deemed served.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When is a summons considered served in England if it was sent by second class post?**

Three business days after the date of posting.

See the [1999 Amendments](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2019/1367/article/8/made) to Rule 99 of the [Magistrates’ Courts Rules 1981](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1981/552/contents/made) which makes no mention of the class of postage, only the relevant timeframe:

> (1) [...] a summons requiring a person to appear before a magistrates’ court may be served by—
>
> [...]
>
> - (b) posting it to the person at an address where it is reasonably believed that the person will receive it...
>
> [...]
>
> (4) A summons served in accordance with paragraph (1) shall be deemed to have been received by the person—
>
> [...]
>
> - (d) [...] **three business days after it was posted** [...] in accordance with paragraph (1)(b)...
>
> [*non-relevant details omitted*]

Note that by picking a random council from Google, Oxford's [Council Tax Debt Recovery Procedure](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.oxford.gov.uk/download/downloads/id/445/council_tax_debt_recovery_procedure.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjf2tHMgLf3AhXUQkEAHaApBuIQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0FWzxIi6B2rResrt80PCxy) which says:

> The summons will normally be served by second class post.

It is entirely likely that this is the national norm, but all other local councils may be found via the [dot.gov](https://www.gov.uk/find-local-council) website, in case one would like to check specific policies for their own locality.

Comment: Would this mean that if I've paid the outstanding amount before the three business days (I paid it today), that the debt was settled before the summons was served?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. This is probably a worthy question to post in its own right!